# error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment. in WSL when trying to run Carla simulator

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run ./CarlaUE4.sh in the WSL, I obtain the following error:

```
4.22.3-0+++UE4+Release-4.22 517 0
Disabling core dumps.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
CarlaUE4-Linux-Shipping: ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:434: __pthread_mutex_lock_full: Assertion `robust || (oldval & FUTEX_OWNER_DIED) == 0' failed.
Signal 6 caught.
Malloc Size=65538 LargeMemoryPoolOffset=65554
CommonUnixCrashHandler: Signal=6
Malloc Size=65535 LargeMemoryPoolOffset=131119
Malloc Size=99968 LargeMemoryPoolOffset=231104
Engine crash handling finished; re-raising signal 6 for the default handler. Good bye.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am new to WSL and Ubuntu. So I would appreciate a lot if you can explain me why is this error happening and how to fix it please. It is Carla 09.7 version